# EXECUTE IMMEDIATE with alter stmt

Tags: oracle

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE' || v_sql || 
                  'ADD PARTITION' || v_partition_name ||
                  'VALUES LESS THAN('||v_limit||')';
```

while executing above query  its showing identifier too long error

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have a malformat string. You miss some spaces when concatenating your command. Try this:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE ' || v_sql || 
                  ' ADD PARTITION ' || v_partition_name ||
                  ' VALUES LESS THAN (' || v_limit || ');';
```